# Question about greatest common divisor.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ Is it correct that
$\gcd(a^2,b^2) = 1$ as well? And if so, how do I prove it?

Comment: I'll remove it. Thank you. Edit: turns out I couldn't remove it. I'll search more in the future before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the contrapositive statement

> If $\gcd(a^2, b^2)\neq 1$, then $\gcd(a, b)\neq 1$

by considering an arbitrary prime that divides $\gcd(a^2, b^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

suppose that $p$ is a prime such that $p|\gcd(a^2,b^2)$

$p|a^2 \implies p|a$ (because $p$ is prime)

similarly $p|b^2 \implies p|b$

$p|\gcd(a,b)=1$ which is impossible.

Therefore $gcd(a^2,b^2)=1$